# How to use variable table name in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure running on a database for a WordPress multisite installation. The structure of the WP database has the same table for every subsite with a unique ID. For example:

wp_2_taxonomy
wp_3_taxonomy

Those are the same tables but one is for subsite 2 and the other for subsite 3. The stored procedure I have needs to run against both of the tables. So far the only way I've been able to do this successfully is have two versions of the same procedure, one for each subsite ID.

Is there a way I can have just one procedure that can accept the subsite ID and create the table name dynamically?

Comment: Doesn't WP use PHP? Can't you do the substitution there instead of in the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a prepared statement to construct the table name dynamically.

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('
    SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM wp_', siteID, '_taxonomy
    WHERE otherCol = ?');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1 USING param_otherCol;
```

Comment: ok i'm testing this now and have a variation that works. `SET @siteID := "5"; SET @sql := CONCAT("SELECT p.post_author FROM wp_",@siteID,"_posts p WHERE p.id = 31"); PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql; EXECUTE stmt1;`. your original suggestion throws an error on CONCAT. i have tried several variations, but everything i have tried that starts with `PREPARE stmt1 FROM CONCAT` errors out.

Comment: I forgot that PREPARE requires just a variable name, not any expression.